# What should I learn

Tags: android, android-studio

So, I have been making simple apps with Android Studio for a while now. Now I want to move into the game development section. What do I need to learn to make games. I know a little bit on Java, but i do not know on what learn specifically to make games. What do i NEED to know to make games in Android Studio. If you guys have any websites or tutorials that you found handy please share them with me.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to learn different type of game engine like Unity 3D to develop application.

Comment: There are game engines ,where you can build cross platform games.like Unity3D,Unreal game engine.In Unity3D you have to learn C# or JS, in Unreal you have to referr c++.But there are so many game engines for JAVA as well

Comment: AndEngine is another game engine.

Comment: http://www.apress.com/9781430239871

Comment: http://www.allitebooks.com/learning-unity-android-game-development/ are some of books to refer

Answer (score 2):

> If you’re an Android app programmer who’s thinking about getting into game development, chances are you are planning on writing code in Java. If you’re a game development veteran who’s thinking of bringing games to Android, it’s likely that you prefer to do everything in C++.
>
> The side-scrolling action game that I wrote, Replica Island, is entirely Java. It uses OpenGL ES 1.0 to draw and is backwards compatible to Android 1.5. It runs at a good frame rate (close to 60 fps on the G1) across almost all Android devices. In fact, many of the popular games on Android Market were written in Java, so if you’re the type of person who finds coding in C++ like speaking in tongues, you can rest easy in the knowledge that Java on Android is perfectly viable for games.
>
> That said, native code is the way to go if your game needs to run as fast as possible. We’ve just released the fourth revision of our Native Development Kit for Android, and it includes a number of improvements that are particularly useful to game developers. Using the NDK, you can compile your code into a shared library, wrap it in a thin Java shell to manage input and lifecycle events, and do all of the heavy lifting in C++ with regular OpenGL ES APIs. As of Revision 4, you can also draw directly into Java Bitmap pixel buffers from native code, which should be faster than loading bitmaps as GL textures every frame for 2D games that want to do their own scene compositing. Revision 4 also (finally!) includes gdb support for debugging your native code on the device.
>
> You should know that when using the NDK, you don’t have access to Android Framework APIs. There’s no way, for example, to play audio from C++ (though we announced at Google I/O our intention to support OpenSL ES in the future). Some developers use the AudioTrack API to share a direct buffer with native code that mixes and generates a PCM stream on the fly, and many call from C++ into the Java SoundPool interface. Just be aware that for this type of work, a jump through JNI back into Java code is required.

~Chris Pruett
Directly copied and posted here. 
Original Article: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/game-development-for-android-quick.html